# Reason for NBA All Star Game wild card players

Tags: nba

Are the wild card players picked before reserve players to play in the game, if not, when, and for what reason, are they picked to play?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your question seems to suggest that "wild card" players and "reserve" players are different picks.   But wild card is just a particular segment of the reserve players.